# Use of BOOST property_tree / iostreams / filesystem / foreach - results with a Link Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, wstring, boost-iostreams

I try to build a project, utilizing `boost/property_tree` with Boost `xml_parser`, upon a `std::wstring` full_path. But I get a link error (See below).

```
#include <filesystem> // C++17
#include <codecvt> // C++11
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void CMainFrame::OnGroup(UINT nID)
{
    // Prepare wstring group-name:
    std::string group_name = m_id_to_string[nID]; //AG: PATCH
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring group_name_w = converter.from_bytes(group_name);

    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    // Populate tree structure pt:
    ptree pt;
    boost::filesystem::wpath full_path = CEngine::Instance().GetGroupDirectory() + group_name_w;
    boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source fs(full_path);
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source> fsstream(fs);
    read_xml(fsstream, pt);

    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type const& v, pt.get_child("Group"))
    {
        unsigned int DeviceId, GridId, MonitorId;

        if (v.first == "Item")
        {
            DeviceId = v.second.get<unsigned int>("DeviceId");
            GridId = v.second.get<unsigned int>("GridId");
            MonitorId = v.second.get<unsigned int>("MonitorId");
        }
    };
}
```

I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BFC, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>MainFrm.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_67.lib'
1>Done building project "BFC.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any idea?

Comment: Seems that boost is badly installed/configured so linker can't find the files it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries of boost are not header only and so those need to be built. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iostreams/doc/installation.html